# Asynch autocomplete with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete

I want to add autocompletion to an input form with data from my server. The data given on the address `/countries/search` is returned in JSON like this:

```
[{"name":"Afghanistan","code":"AF"},{"name":"Aland Islands","code":"AX"},{"name":"Albania","code":"AL"}]
```

This is my code:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<input type="text" name="countries" id="tags"/>
<script>
    $(function () {
        $("#tags").autocomplete({
            source: "/countries/search/"
        });
    });
</script>
```

When I type something into the field the server receives a request but the autocompletion looks a bit strange and does not contain any data:

[image: autocompletion]

Why does this happen and how can I fix this?

**Edit:**

I found out that the data from `/countries/search` should be a JSON object with just the names inside.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the documentation [here](https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/) your source needs to be a Javascript array. So i suggest you make an ajax request to you server and call this method on the success callback.

Something along the lines of:

```
$.ajax({
  url: '/countries/search/',
  type: 'GET',
  success: function(data) {
    $("#tags").autocomplete({
        source: data
    });
  },
  error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){

  }
});
```

Comment: When I try your code the ajax part is executed when the page is loaded and not when I type something in the input form. Do forgot I have to modify your code? Sorry, I'm pretty new to javascript.

Comment: Are you getting the data in the success callback? Put a `console.log(data)` before the `autocomplete` part.

Comment: Yes, I get a JSON array with all the 3 countries in the response.

Comment: Also there is no need to scope the jquery reference, i will edit my answer.

Comment: The ajax part is still only executed when the page is loaded and not when I type something. How can I fix this?

Comment: You would need to save the returned data in a global array and then pass that to the source attribute.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96461/discussion-between-sandeep-s-and-peter).

Comment: I hope my answer solved your problem.If yes do accept it and close the question. If not, do let me know so i can improve the answer